# Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart

guys, I have a problem to get value from this future function.

```
Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(siteAddress + '?apikey=' + apiKey);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      double price = data['rate'];
      String finalData = price.toStringAsFixed(0);
      return finalData;
    }else
      print(response.statusCode);
  }

Text(getData.toString());
```

when I use this in Text widget I get Instance of 'Future' error.

Comment: Are you missing some brackets? e.g. getData().toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getData()` returns a `Future<String>`, therefore we should re-write it as follows:

```
Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(siteAddress + '?apikey=' + apiKey);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      double price = data['rate'];
      String finalData = price.toStringAsFixed(0);
      return finalData;
    }else
      print(response.statusCode);
}
```

And use it in the `Text` `Widget` by the means of a `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data);
    } else {
      return Text('Loading...');
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: Or a FutureProvider from the Riverpod package: https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/all/FutureProvider-class.html